# Answer Buttons (True, False, Yes and No) are not appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble display "True", "False", "Yes" and "No" buttons in a appended row.

I have an application here: [Application](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/QandATable2.php)

Please follow these steps in order to use application:

**1. When you open application, you will see a green plus button, click
    on this button, a modal window will appear with a search bar inside.**

**2. In the search bar type in the following "orange" (without double
    quotes) and then submit the search.**

**3. A row will appear matching the term from the search with the term
    under the "Question" column. You will see that under the "Answer"
    column that the answer is "True". Please click on the "Add" button
    to add the contents from the row.**

**4. You will see that on the right hand side, that it displays the
    "True" and "False" buttons and that the "True" button is highlighted
    green. This is fine.**

But below is where the problem occurs:

**1. Click on the "Add Question" button, this will append a row
    underneath and will copy the controls from above.**

**2. Now within the row you have just appended you will see another green
    plus button, click on this button and perform steps 2 and 3 again.**

You can see that within the appended row, that it does not display the "True" or "False" buttons at all. So my question is that within an appended row, how come when I add a question from the modal window, that it does not display the "True" or "False" buttons if the answer is "True" or "False"? This also happens with the "Yes" and "No" buttons as well.

The whole code is displayed in the jsfiddle here (The functions which opens the modal window is at the bottom of the javascript section of the fiddle):

http://jsfiddle.net/WZKrP/6/

CODE:

```
function plusbutton(plus_id) {
    // Set global info
    plusbutton_clicked = plus_id;
    // Display an external page using an iframe
    var src = "previousquestions.php";
    $.modal('<iframe src="' + src + '" style="border:0;width:100%;height:100%;">');
    return false;
}

    function addwindow(numberAnswer, gridValues, btn) {

        if (btn == "True" || btn == "False" || btn == "Yes" || btn == "No") {
            var answers = '#answer' + btn;
            var answersrow = '#answer' + btn + 'Row';
        } else {
            var answers = $.map(btn.split(''), function(chr) {
                return "#answer" + chr;
            }).join(', ');
            var answersrow = $.map(btn.split(''), function(chr) {
                return "#answer" + chr + "Row";
            }).join(', ');
        }

        var myNumbers = {};
        myNumbers["True or False"] = "True or False";
        myNumbers["Yes or No"] = "Yes or No";

        gridValues = myNumbers[gridValues];

        if ($(plusbutton_clicked).attr('id') == 'mainPlusbutton') {



            if (gridValues == "True or False") {
                $('#btn' + 'TrueorFalse').trigger('click');

            }

            else if (gridValues == "Yes or No") {
                $('#btn' + 'YesorNo').trigger('click');
            }



            $('#answerSection').find('.answerBtnsOn').trigger('click');
            $(answers).trigger('click');

        } else {

            if (gridValues == "True or False") {
                $(plusbutton_clicked).closest('tr').find('input.gridTxtRow').val(gridValues).parent().append($('.optionTypeTbl'));
                $('#btn' + 'TrueorFalse').trigger('click');

            }

            else if (gridValues == "Yes or No") {
                $(plusbutton_clicked).closest('tr').find('input.gridTxtRow').val(gridValues).parent().append($('.optionTypeTbl'));
                $('#btn' + 'YesorNo').trigger('click');
            }


        }

        $('#btn' + gridValues).trigger('click');
        $(plusbutton_clicked).closest('tr').find('.answerBtnsOn').trigger('click');
        $(plusbutton_clicked).closest('tr').find(answersrow).trigger('click');


        $.modal.close();
        return false;
    }​
```

HTML for top plusbutton:

```
<table id="question">
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<a onclick="return plusbutton();">
<img src="Images/plussign.jpg" width="30" height="30" alt="Look Up Previous Question" class="plusimage" id="mainPlusbutton" name="plusbuttonrow"/>
</a>
<span id="plussignmsg">(Click Plus Sign to look up Previous Questions)</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Below is jquery code where it appends a plusbutton for each row:

```
$('.plusimage').each( function() {

    var $this = $(this);
var $plusimagerow = $("<a onclick='return plusbutton(this);'><img src='Images/plussign.jpg' width='30' height='30' alt='Look Up Previous Question' class='imageplus'/></a>").attr('name',$this.attr('name')+"[]")
               .attr('value',$this.val());

$plusrow.append($plusimagerow);

});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with inline style definiton for each button (`<input class='answerBtnsRow answers' type='button' style='**display:none**' ...>` Whenever you apply CSS class answerBtnsOn there is no directive specified to change display back to inline, block etc. You can add one line to answerBtnsOn class but with !important directive so it would override inline style defined by your jQuery code: `display:inline !important`.

Another way is to utilize jQuery (example: `$('#element').css('display', '');`) to change or remove inline style in jQuery script where it sets buttons invisible.

I would definitely update answrBtnsOn and answerBtnsOff classes avoiding any inline style definitions.

Hope this helps.... Please let us know if you have any questions or concerns.

Comment: So are you saying `display:inline !important` is better or utilizing the jquery?

Comment: Well, it is really up to you. I like to have all or most of my CSS definitions in .css file(s). It gives better control for further adjustments. Whichever way you make it it should work...

Comment: Can you do me favour if you don't mind, can you show how to utilize the jquery in the fiddle provided, it will be easier and quicker for me to see where it goes. Then I can give you points straight away

Comment: Here you go [link](http://jsfiddle.net/salih0vicX/TbV5A/)... Whole script is there; updated... mainly function btnclick...

Comment: Hi, Problem is that for example, if the buttons are "True" or "False" and "True" button was turned on, I still want it to display "False" button even though it is off. At moment for this example your code will remove the "False" button which I do not want.

Comment: I've uploaded fiddle; check updated fiddle version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/salih0vicX/TbV5A/2/) ... I haven't tested this one; it should work....

Comment: In you new fiddle did you just include this `  $btn.css('display', 'inline');`, I can see you commented out the other displays. If it is the only thing you included then problem is same thing, only displays turned on button but not the other button

Comment: Hello salih0vicX are you still there?

Comment: Hi, good morning.. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/salih0vicX/TbV5A/3/) should work for you.

Comment: Nope, still not working, this will not display any buttons if I do this. I think eric in the other answer has the right idea which is "You need to call the same functionalty that occurs from the top + click." Can't you update the fiddle to do it this way instead and see if that can work?

Comment: Not sure what is happening on your end but I've tested it (Firefox 15 and Firefox 16); it worked for me...

Comment: Just checked: it works with IE9; Maxton 3.4.5.2; Opera 12.02... Try to replace only javascript i posted on fiddle for you; plug it in to your online version (with the version you have here: http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/QandATable2.php)...

Comment: Hi, tested it in firefox by copying the code from your jsfiddle into the main application which you can see for yourself. You can see it is is still not displaying the buttons under the "Answer" section in the appended row

Comment: It does - if you follow your own instruction from the problem description. I see it won't make it if you skip your steps from 1 to 4 but I had no idea you needed to skip it... Let me take a look again into the problem skipping steps 1-4...

Comment: Hi, Ok I see change and you are nearly there but there is still a problem. If you go on the application and do the last steps, you see that it works. But then do the 2 steps again but this time type in search bar "human" and add that question. The answer to that question is "Yes" so it should just only show "Yes" and "No" buttons, but problem is that it is still showing "True" and "False" buttons as well. They should be not be display. In other words the "Option" test box states "Yes or No" but it still displays "True" and "False" buttons. Your nearly there though :)

Comment: Also can you do me favour, in your next fiddle can you put comments in where you have made changes in the last fiddle and new fiddle you are going to past, it is so that when I put it in main application, I don't miss any changes. Thanks :)

Comment: Any more ideas to sort this problem out, I really want to give you points but really need this problem fixed

Comment: Hey buddy, after so long you could give some points :-) The problem was in your description of the issue... Time consuming...

Comment: I know its difficult to explain but please look at the screen shot at the bottom provided by eric. Those buttons I want it outputted like that after user clicked on a plus image buttons within the appended row and added a question from the modal window if answer was "True" or "False" (True button is green if answer is "True", False button is green if answer is false). If answer is "Yes" or "No", then it should only display "Yes" and "No" buttons. Please, please give it one more try. If you next try has still not sorted then I will still give you the bounty points. Plz one more try :)

Comment: Okay, I've updated it again here: http://jsfiddle.net/salih0vicX/TbV5A/5/. The only change I made was within `insertQuestin function`; please note two lines with $var $newBtn = ... initialisation. The old one (now commented) was appending [3.Answer block] for the new question and it would always include answers from previous question. That would make duplicated set of answers: one from previous question and another one (if different) from current question. I hope this is what you needed :-) Please let me know...

Comment: It didn't work, changing the code in insertQuestion will mean no true or false button appears when you click on the "Add Question" to append the row as well as no buttons appearing after clicking on the image plus button within the row. But as I promised here is the bounty points for you for at least trying :)

Answer (score 0):

Look I don't think I understand you.  Is this what your trying to do?  [image]

Comment: Yes but within one of the rows, click on the green plus button and do the search and select a question add, you realise the "True"/"False" buttons do not get displayed

Comment: Ok, I see.  You need to call the same functionalty that occurs from the top + click.  I will check the code, but it would be better if you could just post the problem code your self.  Nobody knows the application like you, so it would be much faster.

Comment: How does return plusbutton() differ from what your trying to do with return plusbutton(this)?  I'm trying to understand what your trying to do.  Your question was very lengthy and I have a short attention span.

Comment: return plusbutton(this) picks out the exact row on which the plusbutton was clicked from. So that when it adds details into the row, it puts it in the same row as that plusbutton clicked on

Comment: I post code of where it controls top plusbutton and plus buttons in each row, this is in my question.

Comment: plusbutton().  You don't have the function definition in what you just posted.

Comment: Ok, I also include plussbutton() function and html code for top plusbutton and jquery for appended plus buttons

Comment: okay, I understand where the problem is, I need you to go back to your jsfiddle example, and fill it out properly so I can test my theroy, and post you the solution to your problem. The jsFiddle has broken images, and is not clickable.  please make it an exact working replica. We'll get to the bottom of this real quick.

Comment: The problem is eric that you won't be able to test it in the fiddle because when you click on the image, it opens up a modal window which is linked to another page. You will have to use the main application like you did to see how the application works but the Jsfiddle is exactly the same code as the application. Best thing to do is to put your theory code in the fiddle and then I will have to test it in the main application then get back to you. Is that ok?